# DB.php not found

Tags: php, database, pear

I have this error

```
Warning: require_once(DB.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/www.rosterbuster.com/inc/core.php on line 381

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'DB.php' (include_path='/usr/share/php:/home/g3mini/pear/share/pear:/home/g3mini/pear/share/pear/') in /var/www/html/www.rosterbuster.com/inc/core.php on line 381
```

But when I go to `~/pear/share/pear` or even `/home/g3mini/pear/share/pear`
`DB.php` is right there.

What can I possibly do?

Comment: What about permissions ?

Comment: @Random root has read&write, rest has read only

Comment: On other topics having the same problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036603/php-pear-require-oncedb-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483546/pear-db-class-not-found), you have to install the package from pear...

Comment: I've installed the package with pear install DB @Random

Comment: When I type `pear list` It's right there

Comment: you may have to specify full path... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781839/failed-to-open-stream-even-though-place-exists)

Comment: Fixed it, the home dir had to be 777'd, 766 or lower did not work :/ encrypting your home folder breaks pear I guess

Comment: ok, please post it as an auto-answer then, for other people having the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I had encrypted my home folder.

The fix was `sudo chmod 777 ~` Not the safest thing to do, but it worked.